# ¿Cómo configurar un input type number en HTML5 para tener el separador de decimales como punto?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una serie de input type number en HTML5, pero a modo ejemplo utilizaré

```
<input type="number" min"1" step="0.1" name="hstot"/>
```

Soy de chile y acá el separador de decimales es **","** y el separador de miles es **"."**, pero un cliente me ha pedido que necesita que dicho input y **solo ese input** no tenga separador de miles y que el decimal sea un ".", es decir que los números sean tipo `100.5` - `1001.3`, etc. He averiguado por ahí y me he encontrado con la librería **jquery.i18n.language.js**.

Descargué las librerías e importé los archivos a mi proyecto.

```
<script src="<?php echo RUTA_DOMINIO;?>recursos/js/jquery.i18n/CLDRPluralRuleParser.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo RUTA_DOMINIO;?>recursos/js/jquery.i18n/jquery.i18n.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo RUTA_DOMINIO;?>recursos/js/jquery.i18n/jquery.i18n.messagestore.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo RUTA_DOMINIO;?>recursos/js/jquery.i18n/jquery.i18n.fallbacks.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo RUTA_DOMINIO;?>recursos/js/jquery.i18n/jquery.i18n.language.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo RUTA_DOMINIO;?>recursos/js/jquery.i18n/jquery.i18n.parser.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo RUTA_DOMINIO;?>recursos/js/jquery.i18n/jquery.i18n.emitter.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo RUTA_DOMINIO;?>recursos/js/jquery.i18n/jquery.i18n.emitter.bidi.js"></script>
```

y en el document.ready he puesto lo siguiente, pero no logro ver el resultado deseado:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.i18n( {
            locale: 'en' // Ingles puedes elejir el idioma que necesittes
        } )
})
```

Comment: Colocando `lang="en"` en el input, ¿se soluciona?...

Comment: no se a solucionado al poner eso

Answer (score 1):

El comportamiento natural del browser es mostrar el número acorde al locale de cada visitante. Por debajo el número es en realidad el mismo.

La idea es que si alguien copia el contenido del input y lo pega en excel sean consistentes. Si tú fuerzas el punto y el usuario usa comas, excel no lo leería como número.

Esto es igual al funcionamiento de los inputs de fecha. El atributo global lang efectivamente modifica el comportamiento en Firefox, pero no tiene efecto en Chrome.

Si puedes prescindir de los botones de incremento y decremento, hay muchas librerías que pueden aplicar una máscara a un input de tipo text.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de hacer el cambio, yo evaluaría si lo que piden está bien y ver como se está guardando ese dato después.
Era más sencillo, así que edito mi respuesta. No es necesaria ninguna libreria.
Hay que agregar lang="en".

```
<input type="number" min="1" step="0.1" name="hstot" id="hstot" lang="en">
```

Comment: eh probado con esta librería, pero necesito que el input sea tipo number y al hacerlo asi no me deja aumentar o disminuir el valor

Comment: y si le cambias el type y lo dejas como number, funciona?

Comment: claro si le dejo el type number si funciona el input, pero sigue mostrando el separador de decimales con una coma

Comment: era más sencillo, así que actualicé mi respuesta @JonathanAlarcon

Comment: Hola, espero estés bien , pues al parecer a mi no me funciona, porque el separador de decimales sigue con una coma

Comment: ¿eliminaste el código de jquery? ¿que browser y versión estás usando?
Yo al menos estoy usando Firefox 113.0.2